# Advice required on choosing SQL or NoSQL framework for searching / persisting

Tags: java, mysql, sql, solr, nosql

We are trying to build to backend for a Job Portal for which we are building android and iPhone clients.

Here is a basic field which needs to be persisted/searchable.

1. User meta data and their preferences needs to be stored.

   - category to which user below ( single value )
   - skills of user. ( Multi value )
   - User location in text and in latlng
2. Job data and their searchable fields.

   - Job category ( single value )
   - Job skills ( Multi value )
   - Job location in text as well as in latlng

Some of the basic use cases :

1. When job is about to get posted, we should be able to get candidate list nearby location based on job category/skills and latlng.
2. When job is posted, it has to match the actual candidates and get their meta information and persist in another table/schema.
3. When a new user on boards, get suitable jobs for candidate and store in another table.

This data will be served to android/iphone and web dashboard for serving real time data.

Need your suggestions for choosing the framework considering factors of HA, Scalability, reliability and cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use both MySql and Solr for different purposes. For `persisting` the data, it better to use MySql or like database because they will provide you all the ACID properties. You should `index` your job and user data to `Solr/Lucene` which can serve the real time `search` on your platform and provide `suggestion` for auto-completion feature. Solr also provides geo-location search, which could be used to match users and jobs. You can always build recommendation feature on that. CloudSolr can be configured to for HA and Scalability.

Comment: Thanks for your comments abhishek.

Answer (score 0):

For searching give [Solr/Lucene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr) a try. It is extremely scalable, battle-tested and mature.

Answer (score 0):

They are different tools with different advantages and disadvantages.  Both are used on a massive scale.  For small projects the business answer is probably "Do what you know, because it will save you developer-hours."

Just be sure it doesn't lock you into a situation where it's hard to make a change you want down the road.  See, e.g., http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/